# Centos Yum [Errno -1] Header is not complete. Trying other mirror

Tags: linux, networking, centos, proxy, yum

I have problem with my yum, I am trying to install subversion or any other software I am getting any error [Errno -1] Header is not complete.
Trying other mirror all the time. I am running CentOS release 5 (Final) on kernel 2.6.18-53.1.21.el5PAE i386, I am behind a proxy. I have other flavours(centos,redhat,fedora) of linux that have the same network settings but they are able to update and install with yum. I have tried to do a yum clean all and then yum -y update but to no success. Your help is very welcome.

Comment: From what you are telling us, I can only assume the proxy is your problem. Even though the other Linux distros do work, I suggest you check your proxy settings. Can you do a wget of a package in the repository successfully?

Comment: Thanx wzzrd, I am able to wget, I have made it to by pass the proxy but I can seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make it work some upstream proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your CentOS system to use a proxy?

Create /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh:

```
export http_proxy=http://host.com:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://host.com:port/
export no_proxy=.domain.com
export HTTP_PROXY=http://host.com:port/
export FTP_PROXY=http://host.com:port/
```

Restart shell (or run those commands manually) and your proxy should be set up including yum.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but it still brings out that error, If I may ask why is this server exceptional from others? I have installed Centos behind a proxy but never had to run export profile environment variables.